# MySQL select all subquery rows with minimum value

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to select all rows of a subquery with the minimum value in a given field. Here's some toy examples of the techniques I've tried so far:

```
-- 1.
select
    id, min(foo)
from
    (select 1 AS id, 2 AS foo
    union select 2 AS id, 2 AS foo
    union select 3 AS id, 3 AS foo) a;

-- 2.
select
    min(foo)
from
    (     
          select 1 AS id, 2 AS foo, 0 AS const
    union select 2 AS id, 2 AS foo, 0 AS const
    union select 3 AS id, 3 AS foo, 0 AS const) a
group by const;

-- 3.
select
    id
from
    (select 1 AS id, 2 AS foo
    union select 2 AS id, 2 AS foo
    union select 3 AS id, 3 AS foo) a
where id = (select id from a where min(foo) = foo);

-- 4.
select
    id
from
    (select 1 AS id, 2 AS foo
    union select 2 AS id, 2 AS foo
    union select 3 AS id, 3 AS foo) a
where foo = (select min(foo));

-- 5.
select r.*
from
(
    select min(foo) t
    from
        (select 1 AS id, 2 AS foo
        union select 2 AS id, 2 AS foo
        union select 3 AS id, 3 AS foo) a
) m
INNER JOIN a ON m.t = r.foo;
```

The actual query I'm working on is similar to the examples, in that it's made up of several smaller queries UNIONed together. The overall goal here is to lookup a row in a *central* table based on the fields of an association table *k* to which it is joined, where *k* is highest priority table. The result is a sort of tree view of rows from similar (but different tables).

I've mentioned this so in case someone can see that I'm going about this in a roundabout way they can shed some light on the bigger picture. But for now my angle is to select by a taking a minimum value on a field in the subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by foo
limit 1;
```

Note:  this only returns one row with the minimum, even if there are duplicates.  The `t` is your subquery or table.

If you want all of them, then you need to include the table definition twice:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.foo = (select min(t2.foo) from t t2);
```

Comment: "you need to include the table definition twice" -- that's what I was afraid of. My subquery is a beast.

Comment: @JeffCarpenter . . . The first method doesn't have this limitation.  If you need duplicates, then a view is another possibility.